# Webservice failure to call

Tags: apex, webservices, wsdl2apex

Please find the class below. The method called is ASCS_DaaS_APISoap. I am unable to understand where it breaks and not fetching real data.Can some one please help me out in this?
//Generated by wsdl2apex

```
public class daasImshealthCom {
public class GetHCPRegulatoryData_element {
    public String strInputXML;
    private String[] strInputXML_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML'};
}
public class GetHCPProfileV2Response_element {
    public String GetHCPProfileV2Result;
    private String[] GetHCPProfileV2Result_type_info = new String[]{'GetHCPProfileV2Result','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'GetHCPProfileV2Result'};
}
public class LookupHCPResponse_element {
    public String LookupHCPResult;
    private String[] LookupHCPResult_type_info = new String[]{'LookupHCPResult','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'LookupHCPResult'};
}
public class SubmitForHCOMatching_element {
    public String strInputXML;
    private String[] strInputXML_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML'};
}
public class GetUsageResponse_element {
    public String GetUsageResult;
    private String[] GetUsageResult_type_info = new String[]{'GetUsageResult','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'GetUsageResult'};
}
public class ASCS_DaaS_APISoap {
    public String endpoint_x = GetXMLEndPoint();
    public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
    public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
    public String clientCertName_x;
    public String clientCert_x;
    public String clientCertPasswd_x;
    public Integer timeout_x;
    private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/', 'daasImshealthCom'};
    public String SubmitForHCPMatching(String strInputXML) {
        daasImshealthCom.SubmitForHCPMatching_element request_x = new daasImshealthCom.SubmitForHCPMatching_element();
        daasImshealthCom.SubmitForHCPMatchingResponse_element response_x;
        request_x.strInputXML = strInputXML;
        Map<String, daasImshealthCom.SubmitForHCPMatchingResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, daasImshealthCom.SubmitForHCPMatchingResponse_element>();
        response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
        WebServiceCallout.invoke(
          this,
          request_x,
          response_map_x,
          new String[]{endpoint_x,
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/SubmitForHCPMatching',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'SubmitForHCPMatching',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'SubmitForHCPMatchingResponse',
          'daasImshealthCom.SubmitForHCPMatchingResponse_element'}
        );
        response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
        return response_x.SubmitForHCPMatchingResult;
    }

    private String GetXMLEndPoint()
    {
        String retVal='';
        PVS_Parameter_ims__c  searchParam= [Select Id,End_Point_ims__c, App_ID_ims__c, Client_ID_ims__c,Client_Req_ID_ims__c,Password_ims__c,UserName_ims__c FROM PVS_Parameter_ims__c where Name='PVSLookupsPROD' ORDER By Id ];   

        return searchParam.End_Point_ims__c;
    } 

    public String SubmitForHCOMatching(String strInputXML) {
        daasImshealthCom.SubmitForHCOMatching_element request_x = new daasImshealthCom.SubmitForHCOMatching_element();
        daasImshealthCom.SubmitForHCOMatchingResponse_element response_x;
        request_x.strInputXML = strInputXML;
        Map<String, daasImshealthCom.SubmitForHCOMatchingResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, daasImshealthCom.SubmitForHCOMatchingResponse_element>();
        response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
        WebServiceCallout.invoke(
          this,
          request_x,
          response_map_x,
          new String[]{endpoint_x,
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/SubmitForHCOMatching',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'SubmitForHCOMatching',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'SubmitForHCOMatchingResponse',
          'daasImshealthCom.SubmitForHCOMatchingResponse_element'}
        );
        response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
        return response_x.SubmitForHCOMatchingResult;
    }
    public String GetUsage(String strInputXML) {
        daasImshealthCom.GetUsage_element request_x = new daasImshealthCom.GetUsage_element();
        daasImshealthCom.GetUsageResponse_element response_x;
        request_x.strInputXML = strInputXML;
        Map<String, daasImshealthCom.GetUsageResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, daasImshealthCom.GetUsageResponse_element>();
        response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
        WebServiceCallout.invoke(
          this,
          request_x,
          response_map_x,
          new String[]{endpoint_x,
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/GetUsage',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'GetUsage',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'GetUsageResponse',
          'daasImshealthCom.GetUsageResponse_element'}
        );
        response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
        return response_x.GetUsageResult;
    }
    public String GetHCPLicenseDatav2(String strInputXML) {
        daasImshealthCom.GetHCPLicenseDatav2_element request_x = new daasImshealthCom.GetHCPLicenseDatav2_element();
        daasImshealthCom.GetHCPLicenseDatav2Response_element response_x;
        request_x.strInputXML = strInputXML;
        Map<String, daasImshealthCom.GetHCPLicenseDatav2Response_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, daasImshealthCom.GetHCPLicenseDatav2Response_element>();
        response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
        WebServiceCallout.invoke(
          this,
          request_x,
          response_map_x,
          new String[]{endpoint_x,
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/GetHCPLicenseDatav2',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'GetHCPLicenseDatav2',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'GetHCPLicenseDatav2Response',
          'daasImshealthCom.GetHCPLicenseDatav2Response_element'}
        );
        response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
        return response_x.GetHCPLicenseDatav2Result;
    }
    public String GetHCPProfileV2(String strInputXML) {
        daasImshealthCom.GetHCPProfileV2_element request_x = new daasImshealthCom.GetHCPProfileV2_element();
        daasImshealthCom.GetHCPProfileV2Response_element response_x;
        request_x.strInputXML = strInputXML;
        Map<String, daasImshealthCom.GetHCPProfileV2Response_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, daasImshealthCom.GetHCPProfileV2Response_element>();
        response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
        WebServiceCallout.invoke(
          this,
          request_x,
          response_map_x,
          new String[]{endpoint_x,
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/GetHCPProfileV2',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'GetHCPProfileV2',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'GetHCPProfileV2Response',
          'daasImshealthCom.GetHCPProfileV2Response_element'}
        );
        response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
        return response_x.GetHCPProfileV2Result;
    }
    public String GetHCPCSRDataV2(String strInputXML) {
        daasImshealthCom.GetHCPCSRDataV2_element request_x = new daasImshealthCom.GetHCPCSRDataV2_element();
        daasImshealthCom.GetHCPCSRDataV2Response_element response_x;
        request_x.strInputXML = strInputXML;
        Map<String, daasImshealthCom.GetHCPCSRDataV2Response_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, daasImshealthCom.GetHCPCSRDataV2Response_element>();
        response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
        WebServiceCallout.invoke(
          this,
          request_x,
          response_map_x,
          new String[]{endpoint_x,
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/GetHCPCSRDataV2',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'GetHCPCSRDataV2',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'GetHCPCSRDataV2Response',
          'daasImshealthCom.GetHCPCSRDataV2Response_element'}
        );
        response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
        return response_x.GetHCPCSRDataV2Result;
    }
    public String LookupHCPV2(String strInputXML) {
        daasImshealthCom.LookupHCPV2_element request_x = new daasImshealthCom.LookupHCPV2_element();
        daasImshealthCom.LookupHCPV2Response_element response_x;
        request_x.strInputXML = strInputXML;
        Map<String, daasImshealthCom.LookupHCPV2Response_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, daasImshealthCom.LookupHCPV2Response_element>();
        response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
        WebServiceCallout.invoke(
          this,
          request_x,
          response_map_x,
          new String[]{endpoint_x,
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/LookupHCPV2',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'LookupHCPV2',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'LookupHCPV2Response',
          'daasImshealthCom.LookupHCPV2Response_element'}
        );
        response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
        return response_x.LookupHCPV2Result;
    }
    public String LookupHCP(String strInputXML) {
        daasImshealthCom.LookupHCP_element request_x = new daasImshealthCom.LookupHCP_element();
        daasImshealthCom.LookupHCPResponse_element response_x;
        request_x.strInputXML = strInputXML;
        Map<String, daasImshealthCom.LookupHCPResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, daasImshealthCom.LookupHCPResponse_element>();
        response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
        WebServiceCallout.invoke(
          this,
          request_x,
          response_map_x,
          new String[]{endpoint_x,
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/LookupHCP',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'LookupHCP',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'LookupHCPResponse',
          'daasImshealthCom.LookupHCPResponse_element'}
        );
        response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
        return response_x.LookupHCPResult;
    }
    public String GetHCPRegulatoryData(String strInputXML) {
        daasImshealthCom.GetHCPRegulatoryData_element request_x = new daasImshealthCom.GetHCPRegulatoryData_element();
        daasImshealthCom.GetHCPRegulatoryDataResponse_element response_x;
        request_x.strInputXML = strInputXML;
        Map<String, daasImshealthCom.GetHCPRegulatoryDataResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, daasImshealthCom.GetHCPRegulatoryDataResponse_element>();
        response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
        WebServiceCallout.invoke(
          this,
          request_x,
          response_map_x,
          new String[]{endpoint_x,
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/GetHCPRegulatoryData',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'GetHCPRegulatoryData',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'GetHCPRegulatoryDataResponse',
          'daasImshealthCom.GetHCPRegulatoryDataResponse_element'}
        );
        response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
        return response_x.GetHCPRegulatoryDataResult;
    }
    public String GetHCPLicenseData(String strInputXML) {
        daasImshealthCom.GetHCPLicenseData_element request_x = new daasImshealthCom.GetHCPLicenseData_element();
        daasImshealthCom.GetHCPLicenseDataResponse_element response_x;
        request_x.strInputXML = strInputXML;
        Map<String, daasImshealthCom.GetHCPLicenseDataResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, daasImshealthCom.GetHCPLicenseDataResponse_element>();
        response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
        WebServiceCallout.invoke(
          this,
          request_x,
          response_map_x,
          new String[]{endpoint_x,
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/GetHCPLicenseData',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'GetHCPLicenseData',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'GetHCPLicenseDataResponse',
          'daasImshealthCom.GetHCPLicenseDataResponse_element'}
        );
        response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
        return response_x.GetHCPLicenseDataResult;
    }
    public String GetHCPProfile(String strInputXML) {
        daasImshealthCom.GetHCPProfile_element request_x = new daasImshealthCom.GetHCPProfile_element();
        daasImshealthCom.GetHCPProfileResponse_element response_x;
        request_x.strInputXML = strInputXML;
        Map<String, daasImshealthCom.GetHCPProfileResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, daasImshealthCom.GetHCPProfileResponse_element>();
        response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
        WebServiceCallout.invoke(
          this,
          request_x,
          response_map_x,
          new String[]{endpoint_x,
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/GetHCPProfile',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'GetHCPProfile',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'GetHCPProfileResponse',
          'daasImshealthCom.GetHCPProfileResponse_element'}
        );
        response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
        return response_x.GetHCPProfileResult;
    }
    public String GetHCPRegulatoryDataV2(String strInputXML) {
        daasImshealthCom.GetHCPRegulatoryDataV2_element request_x = new daasImshealthCom.GetHCPRegulatoryDataV2_element();
        daasImshealthCom.GetHCPRegulatoryDataV2Response_element response_x;
        request_x.strInputXML = strInputXML;
        Map<String, daasImshealthCom.GetHCPRegulatoryDataV2Response_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, daasImshealthCom.GetHCPRegulatoryDataV2Response_element>();
        response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
        WebServiceCallout.invoke(
          this,
          request_x,
          response_map_x,
          new String[]{endpoint_x,
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/GetHCPRegulatoryDataV2',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'GetHCPRegulatoryDataV2',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'GetHCPRegulatoryDataV2Response',
          'daasImshealthCom.GetHCPRegulatoryDataV2Response_element'}
        );
        response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
        return response_x.GetHCPRegulatoryDataV2Result;
    }
    public String GetHCPSourceDetailDataV2(String strInputXML) {
        daasImshealthCom.GetHCPSourceDetailDataV2_element request_x = new daasImshealthCom.GetHCPSourceDetailDataV2_element();
        daasImshealthCom.GetHCPSourceDetailDataV2Response_element response_x;
        request_x.strInputXML = strInputXML;
        Map<String, daasImshealthCom.GetHCPSourceDetailDataV2Response_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, daasImshealthCom.GetHCPSourceDetailDataV2Response_element>();
        response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
        WebServiceCallout.invoke(
          this,
          request_x,
          response_map_x,
          new String[]{endpoint_x,
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/GetHCPSourceDetailDataV2',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'GetHCPSourceDetailDataV2',
          'http://daas.imshealth.com/',
          'GetHCPSourceDetailDataV2Response',
          'daasImshealthCom.GetHCPSourceDetailDataV2Response_element'}
        );
        response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
        return response_x.GetHCPSourceDetailDataV2Result;
    }
}
public class GetHCPLicenseData_element {
    public String strInputXML;
    private String[] strInputXML_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML'};
}
public class GetHCPLicenseDatav2Response_element {
    public String GetHCPLicenseDatav2Result;
    private String[] GetHCPLicenseDatav2Result_type_info = new String[]{'GetHCPLicenseDatav2Result','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'GetHCPLicenseDatav2Result'};
}
public class GetHCPProfileV2_element {
    public String strInputXML;
    private String[] strInputXML_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML'};
}
public class GetHCPSourceDetailDataV2Response_element {
    public String GetHCPSourceDetailDataV2Result;
    private String[] GetHCPSourceDetailDataV2Result_type_info = new String[]{'GetHCPSourceDetailDataV2Result','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'GetHCPSourceDetailDataV2Result'};
}
public class GetHCPRegulatoryDataV2Response_element {
    public String GetHCPRegulatoryDataV2Result;
    private String[] GetHCPRegulatoryDataV2Result_type_info = new String[]{'GetHCPRegulatoryDataV2Result','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'GetHCPRegulatoryDataV2Result'};
}
public class GetHCPRegulatoryDataV2_element {
    public String strInputXML;
    private String[] strInputXML_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML'};
}
public class GetHCPRegulatoryDataResponse_element {
    public String GetHCPRegulatoryDataResult;
    private String[] GetHCPRegulatoryDataResult_type_info = new String[]{'GetHCPRegulatoryDataResult','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'GetHCPRegulatoryDataResult'};
}
public class GetHCPProfileResponse_element {
    public String GetHCPProfileResult;
    private String[] GetHCPProfileResult_type_info = new String[]{'GetHCPProfileResult','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'GetHCPProfileResult'};
}
public class LookupHCPV2Response_element {
    public String LookupHCPV2Result;
    private String[] LookupHCPV2Result_type_info = new String[]{'LookupHCPV2Result','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'LookupHCPV2Result'};
}
public class GetHCPCSRDataV2Response_element {
    public String GetHCPCSRDataV2Result;
    private String[] GetHCPCSRDataV2Result_type_info = new String[]{'GetHCPCSRDataV2Result','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'GetHCPCSRDataV2Result'};
}
public class SubmitForHCPMatching_element {
    public String strInputXML;
    private String[] strInputXML_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML'};
}
public class SubmitForHCOMatchingResponse_element {
    public String SubmitForHCOMatchingResult;
    private String[] SubmitForHCOMatchingResult_type_info = new String[]{'SubmitForHCOMatchingResult','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'SubmitForHCOMatchingResult'};
}
public class GetHCPLicenseDatav2_element {
    public String strInputXML;
    private String[] strInputXML_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML'};
}
public class SubmitForHCPMatchingResponse_element {
    public String SubmitForHCPMatchingResult;
    private String[] SubmitForHCPMatchingResult_type_info = new String[]{'SubmitForHCPMatchingResult','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'SubmitForHCPMatchingResult'};
}
public class GetHCPLicenseDataResponse_element {
    public String GetHCPLicenseDataResult;
    private String[] GetHCPLicenseDataResult_type_info = new String[]{'GetHCPLicenseDataResult','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'GetHCPLicenseDataResult'};
}
public class GetUsage_element {
    public String strInputXML;
    private String[] strInputXML_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML'};
}
public class GetHCPCSRDataV2_element {
    public String strInputXML;
    private String[] strInputXML_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML'};
}
public class LookupHCPV2_element {
    public String strInputXML;
    private String[] strInputXML_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML'};
}
public class GetHCPProfile_element {
    public String strInputXML;
    private String[] strInputXML_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML'};
}
public class LookupHCP_element {
    public String strInputXML;
    private String[] strInputXML_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML'};
}
public class GetHCPSourceDetailDataV2_element {
    public String strInputXML;
    private String[] strInputXML_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://daas.imshealth.com/','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'strInputXML'};
}
}
```

Please find the debug log section throwing the error here.

21:23:34.621 (1621188057)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[1542]|e|Exception|true|false
21:23:34.625 (1625695608)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[1542]|e|"common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject"|0x6500174c
21:23:34.625 (1625714753)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1542]
21:23:34.625 (1625720317)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1543]
21:23:34.625 (1625747918)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[1543]|System.QueryException.getMessage()
21:23:34.625 (1625815967)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[1543]|Bytes:50
21:23:34.625 (1625834390)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[1543]|System.QueryException.getMessage()
21:23:34.625 (1625846698)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[1543]|msg|String|false|false
21:23:34.630 (1630665798)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[1543]|msg|"List has more than 1 (30 more) ..."
21:23:34.630 (1630680663)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1544]
21:23:34.630 (1630860476)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[1544]|Bytes:83
21:23:34.630 (1630875187)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[1544]|Bytes:133
21:23:34.630 (1630937164)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[1544]|myMsg|ApexPages.Message|true|false
21:23:34.634 (1634972220)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[1544]|myMsg|"core.apexpages.framework.ApexPagesMessage@71795984"|0x6afba142
21:23:34.634 (1634985956)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1545]
21:23:34.635 (1635018762)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[1545]|ApexPages.addMessage(ApexPages.Message)
21:23:34.635 (1635071884)|VF_PAGE_MESSAGE|Sorry.  An error has occurred while searching for the specified HCP record. DetailsList has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject
21:23:34.635 (1635083656)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[1545]|ApexPages.addMessage(ApexPages.Message)
21:23:34.635 (1635089937)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1548]

Comment: What error are you seeing? Nobody is going to be able to give you an answer just based on this...

Comment: I am sorry @LaceySnr .This class is referenced in some other class. Please find the error here. "List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject"

Comment: Then I'm pretty sure it's not in this code at all. Look at your SOQL queries, chances are you're doing something like: `Account a = [select Id, Name from Account]` (but with some other object) and you're getting multiple records back which can't be assigned to a singular instance variable.

Comment: It is most likely the `GetXMLEndPoint()` method above that is causing the issue. As @LaceySnr points out, the SOQL query that is assigned to `PVS_Parameter_ims__c  searchParam` will be returning multiple records. You could put a `LIMIT 1` at the end of they query if you are happy to take the first matching record based on the ordering.

Comment: @Daniel  There is only 1 record with the soql query.

Comment: @LaceySnr  Can you please elaborate I am sorry I can not get it.

Comment: @saikat Somewhere your code has a SOQL query that is returning 2 or more records. You are trying to assign the result to a single instance variable rather than a List. If it isn't the `PVS_Parameter_ims__c` query then it is a similar one in another class.

Comment: @Daniel  All I can find from debug log is that error message is getting generated. Now that refers to the webservice calling class and the particular method mentioned in the question. How to determine the exact soql query?

Comment: please find the section of debug log here.   21:23:34.621 (1621188057)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[1542]|e|Exception|true|false
21:23:34.625 (1625695608)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[1542]|e|"common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject"|0x6500174c
21:23:34.625 (1625714753)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1542]
21:23:34.625 (1625720317)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1543]
21:23:34.625 (1625747918)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[1543]|System.QueryException.getMessage()
21:23:34.625 (1625815967)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[1543]|Bytes:50

Comment: 21:23:34.625 (1625834390)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[1543]|System.QueryException.getMessage()
21:23:34.625 (1625846698)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[1543]|msg|String|false|false
21:23:34.630 (1630665798)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[1543]|msg|"List has more than 1 (30 more) ..."
21:23:34.630 (1630680663)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1544]
21:23:34.630 (1630860476)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[1544]|Bytes:83
21:23:34.630 (1630875187)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[1544]|Bytes:133
21:23:34.630 (1630937164)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[1544]|myMsg|ApexPages.Message|true|false

Comment: 21:23:34.634 (1634972220)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[1544]|myMsg|"core.apexpages.framework.ApexPagesMessage@71795984"|0x6afba142
21:23:34.634 (1634985956)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1545]
21:23:34.635 (1635018762)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[1545]|ApexPages.addMessage(ApexPages.Message)
21:23:34.635 (1635071884)|VF_PAGE_MESSAGE|Sorry.  An error has occurred while searching for the specified HCP record. DetailsList has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject
21:23:34.635 (1635083656)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[1545]|ApexPages.addMessage(ApexPages.Message)

Comment: It will be on line 1542 in the applicable Apex class that is assigning `DetailsList ` Also, please edit/refine your question rather than posting debug logs in the comments.

Comment: @Daniel  "Sorry.  An error has occurred while searching for the specified HCP record. Details" this part is a customization of the message "List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject "

Comment: Thanks Guyz. Thanks for all your help, multiple records were returning for such an SOQL query unexpected for our project.   Line:: RecordType searchParam = [Select Id, Name FROM RecordType where Name=:account_record_type ORDER By Id ];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments we guess that in your code this command (or a similar command elsewhere)

```
PVS_Parameter_ims__c  searchParam = [Select Id,End_Point_ims__c, App_ID_ims__c, Client_ID_ims__c,Client_Req_ID_ims__c,Password_ims__c,UserName_ims__c FROM PVS_Parameter_ims__c where Name='PVSLookupsPROD' ORDER By Id ];
```

returns more than 1 record, and thus it cannot store the result in this one `searchParam`. What you should have done instead is this:

```
List<PVS_Parameter_ims__c>  searchParams = [Select Id,End_Point_ims__c, App_ID_ims__c, Client_ID_ims__c,Client_Req_ID_ims__c,Password_ims__c,UserName_ims__c FROM PVS_Parameter_ims__c where Name='PVSLookupsPROD' ORDER By Id ];
if (searchParams.size() > 0) {
    PVS_Parameter_ims__c searchParam = searchParams.get(0);
}
```

Comment: [Select Id,End_Point_ims__c, App_ID_ims__c, Client_ID_ims__c,Client_Req_ID_ims__c,Password_ims__c,UserName_ims__c FROM PVS_Parameter_ims__c where Name='PVSLookupsPROD' ORDER By Id ] this query returns only 1 record , executed  that.

Comment: So the error is in another SOQL query that has the same issue? Anyway, you should also fix this one as well because you should always be prepared to receive more than 1 record for any SOQL query.

Comment: yes friend!! thanks changing this as well after getting approval.